# run software from anywhere

Tags: path, linux-mint

I am just trying to run all CPS software (Computer Programs in Seismology) from anywhere.
I am using a Virtual Machine with Linux Mint.
What I tried so far is export command:

- export PATH=$PATH:/home/pahan/CPS/PROGRAMS.330/bin

Or to modify the .profile with

- OPATH = $PATH
  PATH=:.:home/pahan/CPS/PROGRAMS.330/bin:$PATH

It is a very simple question, but I would appreciate some help.

cheers!